# IndexIgnore * or Options -Indexes

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've always used `Options -Indexes` to disable directory listing through .htaccess. However, I have seen people using `IndexIgnore *` instead. What's the difference? Which is better than the other?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [`IndexIgnore` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) is a pattern where files in a directory *that has `Indexes` **turned on*** won't show up in the auto-index if they match the pattern.

Say for example, we have a directory, `foo`, and inside that directory, we have an `.htaccess` file, and 3 files, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

If in the htaccess file there is `Options -Indexes`, then by going to `http://mysite.com/foo/`, I will get a 403 Forbidden response, because there is no index file (index.html, index.php, etc) and auto-index is turned off via `-Indexes`.

If in the htaccess file there is `IndexIgnore b`, then by going to `http://mysite.com/foo/`, I will get an auto-index response listing the files, `a` and `c`. The `b` file will be missing because it has been ignored. If we have `IndexIgnore *` in the htaccess file instead, and we go to `http://mysite.com/foo/`, we'll get an auto-index file that is blank, since all files have been ignored.

As for which is better, it depends on what you want. They do fundamentally two different things. Do you want auto-indexes? If not, turn it off `Options -Indexes`. If so, leave it on. If you don't want some things to show up in an auto-index, then use `IndexIgnore`.

Comment: So why do some people solely use `IndexIgnore *`? Wouldn't it be better to use `Options -Indexes` instead?

Comment: Does `IndexIgnore *` display the index screen, but with no files then?

Comment: @bungeshea Correct, you still see the auto-index page but with no files.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any performance differences?

Comment: @bungeshea I don't have any benchmark numbers but I'm sure it is miniscule.

Comment: I am facing a problem where `IndexIgnore *` just doesn't work; `Options -Indexes` does. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

There's one additional advantage of `IndexIgnore` * over -Indexes that's worth noting.

Sometimes it's necessary for automation to determine if a directory exists, via a `GET` or a `HEAD` request, but listing the contents of the directory would be a security issue.  If you do a `GET` or `HEAD` on a directory, and have -Indexes turned on, Apache will return a 403.

However, if you put in a +Indexes, but turn on `IndexIgnore` *, directories that exist will return a 200 to a `HEAD` of `GET` response, but any files or directories within that directory will not be listed in a `GET`