# how to redirect subdirectories having no index file to 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website, **example.com**

**I also have sub-directories as under:**

```
example.com/dir1/
example.com/dir2/
example.com/dir3/
```

Now, I am looking to redirect the visitor to 404 if they they try to access:

example.com/dir1/

**But not in case, when they try to access :**

example.com/dir1/example.php

**Below is my .htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

Options -Indexes
```

with above htaccess i get a default error when i try to access any subdirectory as under:

```
Access forbidden!

    You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

    Error 403

    localhost
    Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12
```

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /404.html you can write your folder name with or condition as we do to hide css/js folder  ------------> RewriteRule ^(?:folderone|foldertwo|folderthree)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

Comment: `RewriteCond` takes two parameters, not three. Your example makes no sense in that regard.

Comment: @Starkeen: I count three – `%{THE_REQUEST}`, `/index\.php` – and ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your .htaccess file!

---

```
ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.html

IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: if you have index it's still throwing 404 when you don't specify the page:
http://website/ - will throw 404
http://website/index.php - will not throw 404

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research and found this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063270/11495586).

It will throw 403 - Access forbidden which is better then auto-index with listed files.